# Implementing a Mux 2:1 using only XNOR, NAND, OR with maximum of 4 gates

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-algebra, circuit-diagram

I had been given a task to implement a `mux2:1` using only these given gates: `XNOR` `NAND` `OR`.

The inputs would be `a`, `b` and `sel` (select).

The output should be `z` (there's no enable input).

The maximum number of gates to be used is 4 (and only those 3 gates).

My idea was this:

**Created a truth table for the `MUX`:**

```
a   b  sel  z
-------------
0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0
0   1   0   0
0   1   1   1
1   0   0   1
1   0   1   0
1   1   0   1
1   1   1   1
```

**Then Created a `karnaugh map`:**

```
sel\ab  00  01  11  10
----------------------
 0   |   0   0   1   1
 1   |   0   1   1   0
```

**The function as a sum of products is:**

```
z=c'a+cb
```

And from here on I tried using [tag:boolean algebra] to expand the function so that it matches an algebraic notation that matches the given gates.

Also, I know that to create `c'` I can used `NAND(c,c)` and for `AND` I can use 2 `NANDS`, but if I apply this to this expression I get 6 logical gates, and the maximum is 4.

Comment: Someone gave me an answer, but I cannot understand what is the thought process behind it:
NAND(  NAND(c,a)   ,  OR( a , NAND(b,b) )     )
Can anyone explain how to get to this answer?

Comment: correction:
NAND( NAND(c,a) , OR( c , NAND(b,b) ) )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing an expression using only NAND, OR, XNOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59410748/writing-an-expression-using-only-nand-or-xnor)

Answer (score 0):

Implementation:
[image: This is the implementation]

function:
[image: this is the function]

algebraic proof:
[image: this is the boolean algebraic solution]