# Writing an expression using only NAND, OR, XNOR

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-algebra, circuit-diagram

I have a 2-1 mux and I'm trying to write `z = s'd0 + sd1`
using only `NAND`, `XNOR`, and `OR` gates (not necessarily all of them).

I tried simplifying it and what I ended up with is `z = NAND(NAND(s', d0), NAND(s, d1))`, but I can't use `NOT` (`'`), so is there a way to write `NAND(s', d0)` without the `NOT`?

Answer (score 2):

You can build NOT from NAND:

`NAND(X,X) == NOT(X)`

[image: NOT from NAND]

Answer (score 1):

NAND gate is an universal gate; you can use it to make any other gate.

`s' = nand(s,s)`

Answer (score 1):

**Simple solution**

Full version of the solution proposed by others is **`(A NAND S) NAND (B NAND (S NAND S))`** .

[image: circuit using nand, 4 gates]

By the way, `NOT X` could also be expressed as `X NAND 1`, not only as `X NAND X`.

**Advanced solution**

**`(S OR (A XNOR B)) XNOR A`**

[image: circuit using xnor and xor, 3 gates]

The latter solution is definitely more interesting:

- It uses a fewer number of gates (though of two different types).
- It uses not [functionally complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness) set of gates (thereby is less trivial).

How to find the latter solution?

1. Construct the [Zhegalkin polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhegalkin_polynomial) of 2:1 mux and simplify it slightly: `(S AND (A XOR B)) XOR B`.
2. Note that the boolean function [dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_principle_(Boolean_algebra)) to 2:1 mux is also 2:1 mux, but for swapped input signals.
3. Now "dualize" the polynomial  (replace `AND` and `XOR` with `OR` and `XNOR` respectively) and swap `A` with `B`.